# What does blinking LEDs mean for GE DFCI AFCI/GFCI Breaker

Tags: circuit-breaker

Breaker in question: http://www.geindustrial.com/products/circuit-breakers/dual-function-circuit-interrupter-dfci

When I press the test button both LEDs blink continuously (blinking does not stop) and the breaker does not trip.
The manual does not mention anything anything about continuous blinking LEDs and GE support has been no help.

If I unplug my PC and surge protector from the circuit the test button does function normally, however I'm not sure why those devices would cause the test function to stop working.

Answer (score 2):

According to the manual..

*Clearing Last Known Trip Condition
The last known trip condition can be cleared by the following process: 
 1. Turn the DFCI to the “OFF” position.
 2. Press and hold the Push-to-Test (PTT) button.
 3. Turn the DFCI to the “ON” position.
 4. Release the PTT button after 3 seconds.*

After clearing last known trip condition the breaker should <strike>stay on</strike> work properly.

If that doesn't work there is a good chance a device on the circuit is bad or the wiring has a fault to ground. Less likely problem could be a bad breaker but probably not in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I think your breaker is faulty in some strange way or not properly installed.

The [Installation Instructions](http://apps.geindustrial.com/publibrary/checkout/DEI-008?TNR=Installation%20and%20Instruction%7CDEI-008%7CPDF&filename=DEI-008.pdf) says that after pressing the red test button:

> The DFCI breaker is functioning properly when:
>     1. The circuit is interrupted.
>     2. The handle moves to the tripped center position (G) as shown in Fig. 1.

and this is clearly not happening in your case.

The LEDs are supposed to indicate the last fault condition - so my guess is that blinky LEDs are telling you the test button isn't producing the expected result.

Do you have the breaker's neutral pigtail wire properly connected in your panel?
A disconnected neutral pigtail is the only condition listed in the instructions which would be expected to produce a result where the breaker doesn't trip when pressing the test button.

If it's installed correctly but still misbehaving then I wouldn't trust it in my panel ...

Comment: This is actually a common problem with GE DFCIs, at least in my experience.  Clearing the last known trip condition usually allows it to reset.  Bad design perhaps

Comment: Kris has it, right and this should be an answer!+ just as GFCI'S were crap in the 70's AFCI's have problems and DFCI's means 2x as many problems.+